# Unable to load library tesseract in R

Tags: r, directory, package, tesseract

```
library(tesseract) # for OCR
```

Results in error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tesseract’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):

unable to load shared object '/dhlib/tesseract/libs/tesseract.so':
  libtesseract.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tesseract’ was built under R version 4.0.5
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Seems like it didn't install correctly. Try re-installing, `install.packages("tesseract")`, and pay attention to errors or warnings during the installation.

Comment: `* installing *binary* package ‘tesseract’ ...
* DONE (tesseract)

The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/tmp/RtmpYBtm6J/downloaded_packages’
> library(tesseract)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tesseract’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/dhlib/tesseract/libs/tesseract.so':
  libtesseract.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tesseract’ was built under R version 4.0.5.` Same problem as before I suppose.

Comment: Can you look in `/dhlib/tesseract/libs/` and see what's there? In particular if `tesseract.so` is there?

Comment: it is not there, no idea how to solve it atm

Comment: What OS are you on? Have you seen the Installation instructions [at the package github](https://github.com/ropensci/tesseract#Installation)?

Comment: I'm on Mac OS so it seems that a simple `install.packages("tesseract")` should work, but I tried reinstalling a few times and nothing changed, still the same error. I'm working on Nuvolos

Comment: Maybe try installing from source (not a binary) and doing `brew install tesseract` from Homebrew as explained farther down.

Comment: not so sure on how to execute that

Comment: Install Homebrew [following these instructions](https://brew.sh/), which is a good thing to have anyway on MacOS. Then open a terminal window and type `brew install tesseract`.